# Probability of a game rolling dice summing to 2018 0r 2019

Tags: probability

A and B play the following game. They roll a fair die repeatedly and write down
the outcomes. They stop if there is a k so that the sum of the last k outcomes is
equal to 2018 or 2019. A wins if there is a k for which the sum is 2018, B wins if
there is a k for which the sum is 2019, it is a tie if there are sums for both 2018
and 2019.
a) Show that with probability one the game will end at some point.
b) Who has a larger probability to win?

my thougths are the game will end since the last sums will be either 2018-1=2017
, 2018-2=2016 ...2018-6 = 2012 
doing the same with 2019 (player B) at least one player will Win

Comment: As I read it the last $k$ rolls have to sum to exactly $2018$ or $2019$ for the game to end.  Say the first roll is a $5$, then a set of rolls that  add up to $2011$, then a $6$ is rolled.  Neither player wins at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Call the state of the game *active* if there is at least one sequence of immediately preceeding consecutive prior rolls with sum between $2012$ and $2017$ inclusive. Call any such sum an *active* *sum*.

Eventually, the state of the game will become active, and once that happens, on every future roll, either the game will end, or the state of the game will still be active.

From an active state, the probability that the game ends on the next roll is at least $\frac{1}{6}$, hence the probability that the game never ends is at most ${\displaystyle{\prod_{n=1}^\infty}} \frac{5}{6} = 0$.

**Claim**:$\;$All active states are neutral with respect to whether $A$ or $B$ wins on the next roll, unless there is an active sum of $2012$, in which case, $A$ is favored.

Subject to the truth of the above claim (defended below), it follows that $A$ wins with probability greater than that of $B$.

**Proof of the claim**:

Assume the game is in an active state, and consider the next roll.

Then there is at least one terminating roll.

Note that a roll of $1$ can't yield a tie or a win for $B$.

If $r$ is the least terminating roll, then $r$ must be a win for $A$, else $r-1$ would be a terminating roll.

If a roll $r<6$ is a tie or a win for $A$, then $r+1$ is either a tie or a win for $B$.

If a roll $r$ is a tie or a win for $B$, then $r-1$ is either a tie or a win for $A$.

Since $r=1$ can't be a tie, it follows that for any nonempty consecutive block of ties, the immediately preceding roll is a win for $A$, and, if the block of ties doesn't end in $6$, the immediately succeeding roll is a win for $B$.

It follows that the winning rolls, arranged in ascending order, alternate between wins for $A$, and wins for $B$.

Consider two cases:

**Case $(1)$:**$\;$There is an active sum of $2012$.

Let $r$ be the greatest winning roll.

If $r=6$, it must be a win for $A$.

Suppose $r < 6$. Then a roll of $6$ must yield a tie. It follows that $r$ is the roll immediately preceding the block of consecutive ties ending in $6$, hence $r$ is a win for $A$.

Thus, for case $(1)$, the alternating sequence of wins for $A$ and wins for $B$ starts and ends with a win for $A$, hence the number of rolls which win for $A$ is exactly one more than the number of rolls which win for $B$.

**Case $(2)$:**$\;$There is no active sum of $2012$.

Let $r$ be the greatest winning roll.

If $r=6$, it must be a win for $B$.

Suppose $r < 6$.

Assume $r$ is a win for $A$. Then a roll of $r+1$ must yield a tie. But a roll of $6$ can't yield a tie, hence the immediately succeeding roll after the block of consecutive ties starting with $r+1$, must be a win for $B$, contrary to the maximality of $r$.

Therefore $r$ must be a win for $B$.

Thus, for case $(2)$, the alternating sequence of wins for $A$ and wins for $B$ starts with a win for $A$, and ends with a win for $B$, hence the number of rolls which win for $A$ is exactly the same as the number of rolls which win for $B$.

This completes the proof of the claim.

**Note:**$\;$Using an analogous argument, for any positive integers $y,n$, if $2018,2019$ are replaced by $y,y+1$, and if the die is replaced by an $n$-sided fair die (with face values $1,...,n$), the same conclusion holds (the game terminates with probability $1$, and $A$ wins with probability greater than that of $B$).